# How to parse OData parameters using regex?

Tags: javascript, java, c#, regex

I know this is asked by many people but not solving my issue

I have a odata query

```
/items?$filter=name eq 'CARPET T!@#&$%^&*()_+-=~<>?,./:";'[]\{}| APE&1-13/32"X42'' or name eq 'Twitter' and subscribers gt '30'&$top=1
```

I got it a solution but it adds next parameter in last value

```
(?<Filter>(?<Resource>.+?)\s(?
<Operator>eq|ne|gt|ge|lt|le|add|sub|mul|div|mod|)\s'?(?<Value>.+?)'?)
(?:\s*$|\s+(?:or|and|not))
```

In last :

```
**Resource -> subscribers
Operator -> ge
Value -> '30' BUT it give '30'&$top=1**
```

Comment: Which language is it: JavaScript, Java, or C#?

Comment: Don't know odata, but that seems like an invalid query. Seems that string literals are single-quoted, but the literal starting with `CARPET` contains `'` and `&` characters without any kind of escaping that I can see, so how would a query parser know where the literal ended?

Comment: Why would the result say `Operator -> ge` when the query says `subscribers gt '30'`? `ge` and `gt` are not the same operator.

Answer (score 0):

Since the framing of the question isn't very clear, I assume you wanted Match 3 to give `Value -> '30'` instead of `Value -> '30'&$top=1`

You WANT to tell the compiler that there may or may not be a punbctuator like `and`, `or`, etc. at the end. But the very last part you added: `(?:\s*$|\s+(?:or|and|not))` simply tells the compiler that there has to be a conjunction OR zero or more spaces at the end.

You should actually be telling it to match zero-or-more non-`'` followed by the end.

## Here's the regex you should be using:

```
(?<Filter>(?<Resource>[^ ]+?)\s(?<Operator>eq|ne|gt|ge|lt|le|add|sub|mul|div|mod|)\s(?<Value>'.+?'))\s*(?:[^']*$|\s+(?:or|and|not))
```

You can view the regex and its result at https://regex101.com/r/saVoqW/1

All you need to do is change the `\s*$` to `[^']*$` and remove the `?` after the quotes and you're good to go!

## Edit

I noticed that in match 2, the 'Resource' attribute was returning ' name' (with a space at the starting), so I changed `<Resources>.+?` to `<Resources>[^ ]+?`, thereby solving the problem :)